# What are default animation transitions for singleTask launchmode

Tags: android

So I changed activity launchMode from singleTask to singleInstance(lets not dig in here why I did that). That affect the animation which is executed when new activity is pushed over the current one.

The problem is that my client want the activity transition for that activity to be exactly as the previous one(like in singleTask launchmode).

So I need to call overridePendingTransition(?,?); after starting the new activity but what params I need to pass here so it will behave just like singleTask?

Comment: You need to create a custom transition ( you can replicate that anim you want ) and set that transition to activity. So just search for custom activity transitions

Comment: Yes I know but does anybody know what is the exact animation triggered from singleTask